# Detect Centroids of Overlapping Gaussian Distributions in Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, cluster-analysis, detection, gaussian

I am currently encountering an image processing problem in python, where the objective is to detect the centroids of multiple gaussian distributions. To be more exact, detect the centroids of overlapping light spots caused by multiple reflections of a gaussian laser beam on a camera chip. As seen in the image below, the gaussian spots are allways alligned equidistantly on a linear plane with a exponentially decaying brightness. The Covariances are tied. The centroids (white x) are to be detected.

[image]

I am currently using a modified gaussian mixture approach to detect the centroids. However the `mixture.GaussianMixture` class from sklean `sklearn` in python requires a number of clusters to be specified in advance (cluster = gaussian spot). This is the first problem that occurs, since i have no idea on how to estimate the number of spots. The second problem occurs when the distance between the gaussian spots decreases and the superposition of the spots becomes less seperateable, as seen in the following image

[image]

The Gaussian Mixture Model brings acceptable results, if the correct number of clusters. Do you have any idea on how to estimate the correct number of gaussians (especially in the second example)? Or do you have any idea if a certain Deep Learning Network is able to detect these centroids accurately?

Already, thank you in advance for all your efforts! :)